# Tkinter quit() freezes window

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, graphics

I got a code that creates a hidden main window in Tkinter (root, Tk object) and than a Toplevel window. I use `after()` to pass the `mainloop()` to the rest of the code, but the window just freezes. I don't want do destroy the app, just to run the rest of the code.

I set the milliseconds in after to 10,000 and noticed that only after 10 seconds, when it prints `After mainloop`, the window freezes/.

Does anybody know why and can I do to make it work?

```
root = Tk()
top = Toplevel()

top.after(10000, top.quit)
top.mainloop()
print 'After mainloop'
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"? How can you tell, since you don't have any widgets in the main window? Also, there's no point in calling `mainloop` on the toplevel window. You should be calling `mainloop` exactly once in a tkinter program.

Comment: By freezes I meant I can no longer move it or even try to close it, and that when I put widgets to test it, they do not react.
However I found a way to overcome this obstacle by calling mainloop() through a thread, So my program is working. Thanks to everyone that tried to help.

Comment: You definitely don't need threads for this little five line program. Are you certain _this exact code_ freezes on you?

Comment: This exact code freezes, but I plan to develop it to something bigger and more complex than 5 lines. This is just to understand and to make my question understandable

Comment: How are you running the code? From the command line with `python the_program.py`, or are you using some other way to run the code?

Comment: I write and use it with Pycharm. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: possibly. I suggest you try running from the command line to see how it behaves, before trying to find workarounds.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a shot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard for anyone to debug with what you posted i will suggest doing `top.iconify()` rather to hide the app. assuming `chat` is window.

Comment: I don't want to close the app, just to gte to the code after the mainloop()

Comment: try `iconify` to see.

Comment: I had a mistake and wrote chat instead of top. I don't understand, where should I use iconify?

Comment: Replace it where you have chat.quit

Comment: When I do that it does what it becomes a little icon but stays stuck in the mainloop() without reaching the following code lines